# Constrain total number of rows in check constraint

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I would like to create a table which can only contain a fixed number of rows at a time, for example just one:

```
create table test (
    someId INT not null,
    comment VARCHAR(4096) null,
    check((select count(*) from test) < 2)
)
```

But the given check-constraint is not allowed:

> Error: Aggregates or subqueries are not allowed in check constraints.
>
> SQLState:  ZZZZZ ErrorCode: 7356

Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to create a table that is guaranteed to have at most one row.  That seems like an unusual use for a table.  Normally, I would recommend a trigger.

Because you only want one row, you can use this hack:

```
create table test (
    someId INT not null,
    comment VARCHAR(4096) null,
    guarantee_one_row int default 0,
    constraint test_only_one_row unique(guarantee_one_row)
);
```

It adds a column with a default value and then defines a unique constraint on it.

I should point out that you can do this with a computed column as well:

```
create table test (
    someId INT not null,
    comment VARCHAR(4096) null,
    guarantee_one_row as ('one row') materialized,
    constraint test_only_one_row unique(guarantee_one_row)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this can work. But it does not guarantee that some DB user does not insert a row with another dummy-int, right?

Comment: I tried it and computed columns cannot be part of constraints: Error: Virtual computed column 'guarantee_one_row' cannot be referenced in any constraints.

Comment: @Beginner . . . I think it should work if the column is materialized.